# Averages and arrays (Codingbat: scoresAverage)

Tags: java, average

I'm working through Java problems on codingbat.com, and have come to a halt at this one, *scoresAverage*. As the exercise description is a bit complicated, I will simply just paste it here:

> Given an array of scores, compute the int average of the first half
>   and the second half, and return whichever is larger. We'll say that
>   the second half begins at index length/2. The array length will be at
>   least 2. To practice decomposition, write a separate helper method
>   
> int average(int[] scores, int start, int end) {  which computes
>   the average of the elements between indexes start..end. Call your
>   helper method twice to implement scoresAverage(). Write your helper
>   method after your scoresAverage() method in the JavaBat text area.
>   Normally you would compute averages with doubles, but here we use ints
>   so the expected results are exact.

The code I have so far does not return any errors, but the numbers it returns are not correct. Can anyone help me with this? My code attempt is as follows:

```
public int scoresAverage(int[] scores) {
  int mid = scores.length/2;

  int average1 = average(scores, 0, mid);
  int average2 = average(scores, mid, scores.length);

  return Math.max(average1,average2); 
}


public int average(int[] scores, int start, int end){
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=start; i<end; i++){
    sum += scores[i];
  }
  return sum/(scores.length);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sum/scores.length` would average the sum of ALL of the numbers; you want `sum/(end - start)` to average a sum of the subset of the numbers

Comment: I would make sum a float/double type and then return a rounded value. Because like this, an average of (as double) 2.9 would be returned as 2 instead of 3!

Comment: @MalaKa This looks like a school assignment, and since rounding was not specified the professor probably does not want doubles to be used in the computation.

Comment: @NominSim I see your point, I thought about that, too. But still, it doesn't make a lot sense to me.. But yeah, it might be desired to only use integers..

Answer (score 0):

This will get the average of each half:

```
return sum/(scores.length/2)
```